# Shares outstanding in quarter report is higher than on Yahoo finance

Tags: accounting, shares, nasdaq

I want to find shares outstanding of Futu Holdings Inc. (FUTU) on NASDAQ.

[Last quarter report](https://ir.futuholdings.com/static-files/f4e232c7-d68f-4a42-84ab-3fbf60079505) shows income statement with `Weighted average number of ordinary shares used in computing net income per share = 1,041,524,160`.

However, [Yahoo finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FUTU/key-statistics/) shows `Shares Outstanding = 135.33M` and calculates market cap accordingly.

Can you help me where is a catch?